# Agile Toolkit 4.3

Tags: atk4

Yesterday I downloaded the new Agile Toolkit 4.3 and found that the licensing and subscription model has been changed. Additionally a "developer sandbox" has been included which launches when the toolkit is first run and requires me to login with a registered account.

While I understand the reasons for these changes, and I'm fully supportive, the sandbox appears to be unnecessarily restrictive. However, there seems to be no easy way to bypass the sandbox, and logging in to the sandbox in a vanilla install of 4.3 leads to a screen where you are forced to choose between a pre-canned Admin or Frontend site.

The key reason for me to upgrade from 4.2 to 4.3 is the introduction of an Application class to support RESTful services. I have no need for either an Admin, nor a Frontend web user interface and yet the sandbox does not provide this option.

Is it possible to bypass the sandbox setup process and, if so, how would one go about doing this?

Looking at this in a different way, the folder structure of the ATK4 library seems to have changed under 4.3. Version 4.2 included documentation on the folder structure and how a developer should setup their application in relation to that structure. I have been unable to find corresponding documentation for Version 4.3 which would give clear guidance on how to build an application around the toolkit without relying on the included sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Tim (i'm author of Agile Toolkit)

Agile Toolkit framework will continue to be available on github. You will find link to github on the [bottom of the page, simply](http://www4.agiletoolkit.org/) select branch 4.3. All of the documentation still applies and you can use the framework (you still need to respect the [license](https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/LICENSE)). Github does not contain "admin" or "frontend", it is included for the convenience of new users.

The licensing terms has slightly changed, Agile Toolkit has always used AGPL and Commercial licensing. The reason to introduce the sandbox is because developers were not respecting the license terms. I also wanted to give easier ability to deploy projects for new PHP developers and for security it can only be done through sandbox.

Here is a blog-post outlining all of the changes: http://www4.agiletoolkit.org/blog/rebooting-agile-toolkit

The folder structure have changed, but it must still be compatible with the 4.2 branch. I've adopted the usage of "public" folders for improved security, but please do look into [PathFinder documentation](http://book.agiletoolkit.org/controller/pathfinder.html) on how to customise folder structure.

Comment: Roman, you say here that the licensing hasn't changed so I must have misunderstood the blog where it talks about changes to the terms and licence pricing. The blog says you have changed from a per annum fee of $130 to a per month fee of $10 and that this is required during the development phase and can be stopped on going live. It also suggests that the need for a licence during development has not changed from V4.2. However in the Licence Store it states that a licence is NOT needed during development (only on golive) and implies that the $130 is a once off price. Could you please clarify.

Comment: You do not need monthly license while you work on your local copy of agile toolkit project. Only when you start sharing it, you need to select the license. That's the only reasonable way to keep it working. But you are correct, licensing terms do change - so I amended my reply. Thanks.